# Python write array to float32

Tags: python, binary

Hi this is I suppose a simple question,

I have an list of len = 259200, how do I write it to a plain binary file?

Many thanks

Comment: What is a `float32` binary file?

Comment: This post doesn't sound correct. What does the array contain and what should be the format you write it in?

Comment: FWIW I think OP means something like "a file full of representations of numpy float32 objects". Question should be cleaned up to that effect by OP or someone knowledgeable of numpy.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: 'plain binary format'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html).

```
with open('whatever', 'w') as f:
    arr.tofile(f)
```

Comment: To use this you need to `import numpy as np` and if `arr` is a list (i.e. not a `numpy array` do `np.array(arr).tofile(f)`.

Comment: Thanks - it is actually a list. When I tried what you suggests it returns 'first argument must be a string or open file'. Any idea?